# Third party Skydrive client for Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, network

Are there any third-party programs for Microsoft Skydrive (but for Mac)?

Skydrive offers 25GB of free cloud storage.

There [is a third-party app for windows](http://www.gladinet.com/) that can access Skydrive.

Comment: please, get a real cloud service like box or dropbox. Sky drive's speed is a joke

Comment: The official Microsoft solution is to use safari 4 or later and access sky drive through the office web apps. Can you edit your question to be more specific how you want to access that service if this isn't what you are looking to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft just released an official [SkyDrive App for Mac](https://apps.live.com/skydrive) according [the the MacObserver's article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/microsoft_releases_skydrive_app_for_os_x_7_gb_free_storage/). So there may be less of a need for a third party one, check it out.

> Users looking for online storage and syncing that don’t want to go the Dropbox route can now check out Microsoft’s SkyDrive app, released Monday for Windows and OS X Lion (via The Verge). The app ties into Microsoft’s existing SkyDrive service and offers Dropbox-like file management and syncing with 7GB of free storage and the option to add 20, 50, or 100GB of additional storage for US$10, $25, or $50 per year, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for someone to be for sure. However, my research on this topic has shown that there are no publicly available native Mac clients for SkyDrive. I'd love to be proved wrong! It is reported that Microsoft is developing one.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft *might* be developing a Mac client, based on [a statement they made in August](http://www.liveside.net/2011/08/27/skydrive-client-app-coming-for-windows-ios-mac-and-android-too/). They have an iOS app already in iTunes, so it is possible they might make a Mac app, too.

It's unlikely there will be a  3rd party client until Microsoft makes it clear whether or not they will developer their own and what the features will be.